# Trouble Uploading an image to a Postgres Database with activerecord API

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am trying to convert my webpage over to the new Twitter Bootstrap HAML approach, but i am running into trouble when uploading an image into a form.  The form is POST to an API that uses activerecord to put the params into the database.  Submitting the app on the old webpage works, and through the API works, jsut not with my new HAML form.  Below is the new and old code for the Icon upload field, as well as the API code where the image is uploaded to the database.

The error I keep getting is "Can't convert Symbol to integer," and I think the problem is lying in taking the [:filename] from the actual uploaded icon.

New Code:

```
    %div{:class=>classes_for_form_input(@data, :icon)}
      %label.control-label{:for => "icon"} *Icon:
        .controls
          %input{:name=>"icon", :type=>"file", :id => "icon", :class => "fileinput", :title => "App Icon", :value=>@data[:icon]}
          %span.help-inline #{help_message_for_form_input @data, :icon }
```

Old Code :

```
<td class="uploadtabletd1l"><label for="icon">*Icon: </label></td><td class="uploadtabletd1r"><input type="file" class="fileinput" name="icon" id="icon" size="18" title="Icon (128x128 Pixels, Max 100 Characters)" />#{tip1}#{iconhelp}#{tip2}</td>
```

API loop to upload the icon:

```
attr = app.attributes()
attr.each do |k,v|

  if @vals.include?(k)
    if k == "icon" then  
      attr[k] = @vals[k][:filename]
    else  
      attr[k] = @vals[k] 
    end  
  end
end
```

The stack error message is giving the below errors because I am using a session :success_message to redirect to a page showing the uploaded app.

```
 NoMethodError at /appdetails
 undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
 file: home.rb location: block in <top (required)> line: 94
/gas/dev/routes/home.rb in block in <top (required)>
 @app = result['appinfo'].first
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in service
  si.service(req, res)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in run
      server.service(req, res)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb in block in start_thread
      block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)
```

The "Cant convert symbol to integer is coming from the following line of code where i try to print the result of the api call to create the app within the database

```
result = @client.createapp(@vals) # This is calling the API to return the vals that were inputted into the database
puts result.to_s
```

Here is the home.rb file: Line 94 is @app = result['appinfo'].first

```
get '/appdetails/?' do
# include some page specific scripts and styles via the layout
@page_scripts = ["jquery.colorbox-min.js", "gass-apps.js", "jquery.rateit.min.js"]
@page_styles = ["colorbox.css", "rateit.css"]

#TODO Handle case for unknown app id
result = @client.appinfo(:app_id=>params[:id])
puts __FILE__.to_s + '(' + __LINE__.to_s + '):' + result
@app = result['appinfo'].first

#get screenshots into an array that the view can iterate through
screenshot_properties = ["screenshot1", "screenshot2", "screenshot3", "screenshot4"]
@screenshots = []

screenshot_properties.each do |screenshot|
  @screenshots << @app[screenshot] if @app.has_key? screenshot
end

@reviews = @client.getreviews(:app_id=>params[:id], :order=>'reverse')['getreview']

@favorite = false
#TODO - a more direct API call would be better than iterating over all the favorites
userFavorites = @client.getuserfavorites()['getuserfavorites']
userFavorites.to_a.each do |favorite|
  @favorite = true if favorite['app_id'] == params[:id].to_i
end

# Increment the view count for this app
plural = "s"
viewcount = @app['view_count']
if viewcount.to_s == '0'
  plural = ""
end
viewcount += 1
result = @client.updateappviewcount(:app_id=>params[:id], :view_count=>viewcount)
```

OK: Dumb mistake in general. I copy pasted the form set over and forgot to include the enctype="multipart/form-data" . However, Sinatra is now returning that enctype is not defined?  Do i need to require this somehwere?

Comment: Another thing to note is that i have run "puts" commands, and puts @vals["icon"] returns the image name before API loop reaches icon, but fails after it reaches the icon loop

Comment: The error is referencing a file that you haven't supplied.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lied in the form tags.  Forgot to include the  "enctype="multipart/form-data" or HAML
 :enctype="multipart/form-data"